# covariance and expectional in proccess

Tags: expectation, brownian-motion, covariance

Show that the process $X=(W_{\sqrt{t}}I_{(1,2)}(t))_{t \ge 0} \in \mathcal{L}_3^2$. ($W$- Wiener)
Additionally calculate, for $t,s \in [1,2]$, $EX_t$ and $Cov(X_t,X_s)$

I have no idea how to start with it. Please help me :(

Is it just : $EX_t=EW_{\sqrt{t}}=0$ ?
And for $s \le t$ $Cov(X_t,X_s)=Cov(W_{\sqrt{t}},W_{\sqrt{s}})=\sqrt{s}$

Comment: It is indeed true that $\mathbb{E}[X_t] = 0, \forall t$. However, to be more precise, you should consider a few cases. If $t \geq 2$ or $t \leq 1$ then $X_t = 0$ and consequently $\mathbb{E}[X_t] = 0$. On the other hand, if $t \in ]1,2[$ then $X_t = W_{\sqrt{t}}$ and consequently $\mathbb{E}[X_t] = \mathbb{E}[W_{\sqrt{t}}] = 0$. 

To compute the covariance function $\mbox{Cov}[X_t,X_s]$, recall that $\mbox{Cov}(W_t,W_s) = \min\{s,t\}$ and split up in cases.

Comment: ok, but I have to calculate it only for $t,s \in [1,2]$ so I don't have to split it into parts. Am I right?
What about the first part of this task? This bothers me harder

Comment: Yes, for some reason I did not read that. Then your calculations are correct, that is, for $s,t \in [1,2]$: $\mbox{Cov}[X_t,X_s] = \min\{\sqrt{s},\sqrt{t}\}$.

Comment: Thanks @Siron !
Any idea for first phase? :(